# Проблема с createmap <messaging.dto>

Tags: c#, oracle, nhibernate

в чем может быть проблема? Есть 2 таблицы ContractCity и  ContractManager. Я хочу промаппить в Messaging.Dto.ContractManager из ContractCity вот так

```
CreateMap<ContractCity, Messaging.Dto.ContractManager>()                    
                .ForMember(dest => dest.CreatedAt, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CreatedAt))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.BranchId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Branch))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.ManagerGuid, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Manager));
```

Но когда захожу в бд строчка manager пустая, т.е. нет записей никаких.

Пробовал через

```
.IncludeBase<ContractCity, Messaging.Dto.ContractManager>()
```

без результатов, в чем может быть дело?

Comment: Дебажте после вызова .Map() и смотрите, что где не так заполнилось.

Comment: почему то даже дебаггер не проходит, но следующая строка то записывается  бд, а эта нет. Хм...